# How to import data in the right monthly order using list.files

Tags: r, import

I have 100 years of monthly data where each month is a file and the file name ends with the year and month of the data.

e.g. "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_1.asc"  is the file for year 1901, month 1 (January).

The problem is when I list my files the order of the files changes, the months 10, 11 and 12 come after 1:

```
files <- list.files(pattern=".asc") 
head(files)

[1] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_1.asc"  "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_10.asc" "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_11.asc"
[4] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_12.asc" "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_2.asc"  "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_3.asc"
```

I can see why that happens, but how can I import my data in the right monthly order?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to import your data in the right order?  That seems unusual to me - in all of the situations I can think of, it would be easier to just sort the records once you had them imported...

Comment: @MattParker If the data files are large, maybe you'd only want to load a few files at a time, but you'd prefer to grab January and February instead of January and October.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `regex` based solution. It works by extracting the year and month from a filename to construct a real date, and then uses the sort order to print the file list.

```
pat <- "^.*pet_([0-9]{1,})_([0-9]{1,}).asc$"
ord_files <- as.Date(gsub(pat, sprintf("%s-%s-01", "\\1", "\\2"), files))
files[order(ord_files)]
```

**EXPLANATION**

We use regular expressions to match the `year` and `month` in the file name. Accordingly `\\1`  matches the `year` and `\\2` matches the month. We still need to convert it to a date. The statement `sprintf("%s-%s-01",`\1`,`\2`)` substitutes the values of `year` and `month` in place of `%s`. The `as.Date` is required to convert the string into a date.

Comment: Could you explain how the `sprintf("%s-%s-01", "\\1", "\\2")` works please?

Answer (score 2):

```
files <- c("cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_1.asc", 
           "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_10.asc", 
           "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_11.asc", 
           "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_12.asc", 
           "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_2.asc", 
           "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_3.asc",
           "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1902_1.asc",
           "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1902_10.asc", 
           "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1902_11.asc")
```

This splits the names on underscores, and selects the last part. (e.g. "1.asc") and removes the ".asc" using `sub`.  Then it converts what is is left into a number and uses `sprintf` on the number to get a 2 character (digit) string.  Then it turns the year and month into a number and `order`s based on that.

```
files[order(sapply(strsplit(files, "_"), function(x) {
    m <- sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(sub(".asc", "", last(x)))) # turns "1.asc" into "01"
    as.numeric(paste(x[length(x) - 1], m, sep=""))
}))]
```

Returns:

```
[1] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_1.asc" 
[2] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_2.asc" 
[3] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_3.asc" 
[4] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_10.asc"
[5] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_11.asc"
[6] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_12.asc"
[7] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1902_1.asc" 
[8] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1902_10.asc"
[9] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1902_11.asc"
```

Comment: thanks, that solves the problem of the months but creates a problem with the years, now I have all the Januaries together (100 years of Januaries), then 100 Februaries....  > head(files2)
[1] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1901_1.asc"
[2] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1902_1.asc"
[3] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1903_1.asc"
[4] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1904_1.asc"
[5] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1905_1.asc"
[6] "cru_ts_3_10.1901.2009.pet_1906_1.asc"

Comment: I am getting an error: `Error: unexpected '}' in:
"+     as.numeric(paste(x[length(x) - 1], m, sep=""))
+ }"`

Comment: I copied and pasted from my terminal what had already been executed. You have to remove the ">" and "+" before pasting it in yours.  I cleaned it up so you should be able to just copy and paste

Comment: thanks this works too (+1 because I can only accept 1 answer)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `mixedsort` function in the `gtools` package.